# Why AccessDeniedException and AuthenticationException be handled differently

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-starter-security

I create a demo app with Spring Boot 2 and Spring Security 5. The source locates at [here](https://github.com/tonny1983/multi-security-config).

It provides two kinds of endpoints -- HTML web pages and REST apis. Therefore, two subclasses of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` are introduced as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class PageSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .and().logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }
}
```

There are three cases which will cause authentication and authorization failed for a REST api call:

1. No credentials provided for a protected endpoint
2. Wrong credentials provided
3. Right credentials provided with wrong roles

The result shows `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException` risen in case 1 and 3, and `org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException` risen in case 2, and the return values for the three cases are:

1. a json error message with HTTP status 401
2. HTTP status 302 redirected to /login endpoint returned
3. a json error message with HTTP status 403

For case 2, the phenomenon has been explained in my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134630/how-to-return-http-status-code-instead-of-login-page-in-multi-httpsecurity-case/64151670#64151670). Generally, it is because the exception will be handled by default error endpoint `/error`, and in Spring Boot 2 the endpoint has been also protected and therefore requires login (for detail -- [Spring security 5 "Bad credentials" exception not shown with errorDetails](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4467#issuecomment-381383356)).

The further question is why case 1 and 3 are not handled by the same mechanism? Why does not the default error handler handle the `AccessDeniedException` with `/error` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP.401 or »Unauthrized« is because the security context didn't receive any credentials. And it also depends on the URL being invoked (static page, role and so on). Normally a browser would display a login dialog. Your illustration does not contain any configuration of this forwarding case to a login form.

HTTP.403 or »Forbidden« is already at the end of the chain: wrong role thus no access (no forward, no browser's dialog).

Does your *SecurityConfig reside in different components/ JARs? I assume not, because you use `@Order`-annotation. If your intention is to have both active at the same time and they're in the same JAR merge them to a single one. This makes it more obvious what exactly is meant without keeping the one or the other in mind.

I also can only guess how your roles are expressed. At least three different options exist for example `@RolesAllowed`, Spring EL or as you did. And mind the difference between Spring's Granted Authority and Role. The latter has to start with 'ROLE_' if not configured otherwise to be found with `hasRole` SpringEL. Everything else ends up as Granted Authority instead.

There are also additional endpoints maybe lacking protection or now being inaccessible, e.g. monitoring- and health-endpoints. Depending on their configuration it might have an effect on all endpoints (I simply assume they would be configured through their properties in a src/main/application.properties or .yaml and not using any @Configuration-class.)

Comment: I'm sorry for missing the client condition. Actually, the 3 cases are all for REST api clients but browsers. As you said, if try to access a protected page without authentication, the browser will be redirected to `/login` endpoint. However, for REST client, it simply gets a 401 status with a json message (try `curl http://localhost:8080/api/data`). This is fine and works as expected. But for case 2, if wrong credentials provided, the REST client expects to get HTTP status with or w/o a json message but be redirected to the `/login` endpoint.

Comment: I'm uncertain what exactly you're asking for. In your question case #2 is explained through exception followed by error-handling which in turn redirects to login-endpoint because being protected. This is what I answered, that standard-endpoints are protected, too due to your security config. And cases 1 and 3 are already handled sufficiently through security context with a HTTP status instead of exception-induced redirect-cascade.

Comment: For case 2, I'm just asking why it is redirected to the `/error` endpoint. According to the [Spring Security document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-basic), `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` will be call last when authentication fails in Basic Authentication, and it just adds a `WWW-Authenticate` header and sets the HTTP status to  401 (UNAUTHORIZED) which is actually the expected result I want. However, in my app, after  `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`, I can see `/error` endpoint is called. So, the question is as mentioned.